# XML highcharts file creation using java

Tags: java, xml, highcharts

the question is how to create this xml file exactly for me to be able to use it in the get function of highcharts?  The CSV file is created rapidly but now i want to create the xml file from the back end which is java.

```
<chart>
  <categories>
    <item>..</item>
  </categories>
  <series>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <data>
      <point>1</point>
      <point>2</point>
      <point>3</point>
      <point>4</point>
    </data>
  </series>
</chart>
```

Upon request:

```
<chart>
<categories>
<item>Apples</item>  these two items must be populated from the database
<item>Pears</item>
</categories>
<series>
<name>John</name>   this one also from database
<data>
<point>8</point>    this is the data part, retrieved from database
<point>4</point>
<point>6</point>
<point>5</point>
</data>
</series>
</chart>
```

I want to create this type of xml structure using a java method or class where i retrieve all the information i need and then pass in into the xml file.

Comment: There are about a million ways to create XML in Java; you may want to narrow this down somewhat.

Comment: Do you have any other need for the XML other than passing it to highcharts?  If not, you should focus your efforts on creating a JSON object to send to highcharts.  Creating XML, just to parse it in the javascript is wasteful.

Comment: @Mark [{"apples":1},{"pears":2}] is not working.. Am using JSF facelets and just highcharts.. Would be grateful if you could throw some more light

Comment: @yash, "not working" is too vague.  You can't produce that on the java side, or your javascript is erroring or highcharts doesn't like it (I am guessing this last one).  Read this:  http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series--data, this is how highcharts expects the data to look.

Comment: @Mark okay thanks but yet can you explain how to create the xml from java?
the gson.toJson(var) produces this [{"apples":1},{"pears":2}] 
Anyway to process it to match highcharts standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, am using xml to populate data for highcharts now.. Thanks for the answer